# How to loop correctly in terraform for_each?

Tags: azure, terraform, terraform-provider-azure, terraform0.12+, azure-rm

**Objective**: Loop through azure subnets via terraform.

**Code That I use:**

**`Main.tf:`**

```
resource "azurerm_network_security_group" "nsg" {
  name                = "nsg-vnet-hub-${var.env}-indoundDNS"
  location            = azurerm_resource_group.rg[0].location
  resource_group_name = azurerm_resource_group.rg[0].name
  tags     = {
    environment = "${var.env}"
    costcentre = "12345"
  }
}

    resource "azurerm_monitor_diagnostic_setting" "nsg" {
      for_each                   = var.subnets
      name                       = lower("${each.key}-diag")
      target_resource_id         = azurerm_network_security_group.nsg[each.key].id
      storage_account_id         = azurerm_storage_account.storeacc.id
      log_analytics_workspace_id = azurerm_log_analytics_workspace.logws.id
    
      dynamic "log" {
        for_each = var.nsg_diag_logs
        content {
          category = log.value
          enabled  = true
    
          retention_policy {
            enabled = false
          }
        }
      }
    }
```

**My root module `variable.tf` :**

```
variable "subnets" {
  type = map(object({
    name    = string
  }))

  default = {
    "s1" = { name = "dns_snet"},
    "s2" = { name = "common_snet"},
    "s3" = { name = "gw_snet"},
    "s4" = { name = "data_snet"}
}
}
```

**Problem I am facing:**

**Error:**

```
network_security_group_id = azurerm_network_security_group.nsg[each.key].id
│     ├────────────────
│     │ azurerm_network_security_group.nsg is object with 7 attributes
│     │ each.key is "s3"
│ 
│ The given key does not identify an element in this collection value
```

Just updated this post, now I get error as above.  I am referring to below documentation

https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/azurerm/latest/docs/resources/network_security_group

Comment: What is the `terraform plan` output?

Comment: @MarkB apologies, I updated my post now, I was missing one variable declaration related to nsg. Now I am presented with error.

Comment: It seems it's coming from a resource which you haven't added to the question?

Comment: @MarkoE it's added. `azurerm_network_security_group` this one

Comment: Nope. It's complaining about an argument which does not exist in any of the resources you added.

Comment: `azurerm_network_security_group.nsg` is an object. You're trying to reference `azurerm_network_security_group.nsg["s3"]` which isn't something that exists. Your syntax is all wrong and it's not clear what you are even trying to accomplish with this syntax.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have only a **single instance** of `azurerm_network_security_group.nsg`. Thus there is nothing to iterate over. To fix your error, it should be:

```
target_resource_id         = azurerm_network_security_group.nsg.id
```

Comment: as you said, I realized its only one nsg. and multiple subnets...by the way, the way of declaration of varaible subnets is correct  in varaible.tf ? What is correct way mention it in tfvars. file.. I have updated my subnet definition in original post.. now when I try to apply `azurerm_monitor_diagnostic_setting` to all subnets..its invalid declaration subnet variable..

Comment: @asp If your subnet variable works and produces the outcome you want, then its fine. If you have issues with it, please make new question with relevant details.

Comment: for now your suggestion worked. I have other issue now i am not able to apply `azurerm_monitor_diagnostic_setting` for all subnets in loop. Shall make a new question... thank you very much